# Can't install google/cloud-spanner with composer, using CMD

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, composer-php, google-cloud-spanner

I'm going to use google cloud spanner database with my web project. So i wnat to install composer. When i run **composer install** command in cmd it shows this message.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for google/cloud-spanner ^1.27.1 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-spanner[v1.27.1].
    - google/cloud-spanner v1.27.1 requires ext-grpc * -> the requested PHP extension grpc is missing from your system.
```

I think this is a problem with my PHP version of some file is missing. Am i right? how to solve this?

Comment: The error message is right there: `google/cloud-spanner v1.27.1 requires ext-grpc * -> the requested PHP extension grpc is missing from your system.` You have to install grpc extension on your computer.

Comment: Here is the tutorial from Google: https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc

Comment: i download the gPRC zip file. Is there are any special way to install it. I have gRPC zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [gRPC for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc) in the first place.

On Windows, you'd have to install the [DLL](https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC) manually into PHP [`extension_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir):

> In what directory PHP should look for dynamically loadable extensions.

File-type `.tgz` might need eg. WinRAR to unpack.

Enable it with `extension=php_grpc.dll` in `php.ini`.

For more information, see [grpc.io](https://grpc.io).

Comment: When i'm going to register the dll file it shows an error.  **The module** "php_grpc.dll " **failed to load. The specific module cannot be found** . I installed it in **windows\system32** path and used the **regsvr32** command to register it.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your setup is but if we move the php_grpc.dll from wherever you currently have it (windows\system32) into the ext folder in the php directory it should be able to find it.